# Is it correct to say that $\lim_{x\to\infty}e^x=\infty$?

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

I saw $$\lim_{x\to\infty}e^x=\infty$$ in  a textbook, but I think the limit of the left part doesn't exist. So left part doesn't equal right part. Am I right?

Comment: There's something called the "extended reals," which is $\mathbb R\cup\{-\infty,+\infty\}$ (that is, the real numbers with the addition of infinity and negative infinity). ($\infty-\infty$ is left undefined, as are others.) Limits are usually thought of, at least informally, as being in the extended real number system.

Comment: In any case, to be formal, the expression $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=\infty$ just means that, as $x$ gets closer to $c$, $f(x)$ grows without bound. Technically, the limit doesn't exist, but people write it like that anyway (because it's thought of as being in the extended reals).

Comment: @columbus8myhw "technically,the limit doesn't exit....." help me out. you can add it as answers, I think it helps to others who also confused about this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you read the lines in your textbook clearly, then you will find there must be somewhere explaining the notation "$= \infty$", which merely stands for, say "gets arbitrarily large", and the symbol $\infty$ does not denote any number.

Usually in calculus we work with the real numbers, and there is no real number called infinity.

To avoid unnecessary confusion, please be informed that the symbol "$\infty$" is not a number in the sense that we do not allow operations with $\infty$. Certainly you can make $\infty$ a number by stipulating suitable operations with it and suitable notions of "positiveness" and "negativeness" as what measure theory does.

If you cannot accept the notation that confused you, you may instead write
$$e^{x} \to \infty\ \ as\ \ x \to \infty,$$
though that makes no substantial difference.

Comment: So that I can improve my answer, may I know why this answer was downvoted by some person?

Comment: Your question is answered! Note that $\infty$ is NOT a real number and that a limit is necessarily a number.

Comment: @user229922  My advice for you is, do not try to read mathematics "term by term", because often times mathematical symbols do not have meaning in their selves. Moreover, doing that is like asking why the "in" and the "in" in "incomplete" have different meaning. It depends heavily upon the given contexts :)

Comment: @Pedro: Yes, of course. But $\infty$ in the calculus level is NOT a number, okay? Of course we can make the concept of infinity in our number fields. But that is not the approach that most college calculus books adopt.

Comment: @user229922 Please see my comments above. Your obstruction, as it seems to me, is that you seem to read mathematics term by term. In the  context under consideration, we *define* the string "$= \infty$" of symbols to be understood as "gets arbitrarily large". Therefore, you do not need to insist on reading the equation term by term, namely no need to understand it as "equal to $\infty$".

Comment: @user229922: Moreover, you are truly encouraged to read your textbook carefully. I believe that every careful, serious mathematician who is able to write a calculus book can never forget to state what I am talking to you :)

Comment: @Chou "Usually in calculus we work with the real numbers, and there is no real number called infinity. " I don't think this is true to be honest. We also work with $\infty$ in calculus to describe limiting behaviours.

Comment: @Pedro: Do you write $\infty - \infty = 0$ or $\infty + \infty = 2\infty$? If not, then you are not working with the infinity.

Comment: @Pedro: Please be reminded that, in mathematics, our concern is always about operations and what we can do with a given class of objects, rather than the objects themselves.The latter is what the so-called philosophers do... You may read some of Hilbert's works; he saw this point long time ago :)

Comment: @Pedro: No, the problem is that some people do not really understand what a definition in mathematics is about.

Comment: I understand this answer. I should take your advice that don't read it term by term.Thank you

Comment: @user229922: No problem! My approach is to give an OP something that is more general than he or she needs, so that it may solve a class of his or her problems at one stroke.

Answer (score 1):

There's something called the "extended reals," which is $\mathbb R\cup\{-\infty,+\infty\}$ (that is, the real numbers with the addition of infinity and negative infinity). ($\infty-\infty$ is left undefined, as are others.) Limits are usually thought of, at least informally, as being in the extended real number system.

In any case, to be formal, the expression $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=\infty$ just means that, as $x$ gets closer to $c$, $f(x)$ grows without bound. Technically, the limit doesn't exist (the definition of limit* never mentions infinity), but people write it like that anyway (because, informally, it's thought of as being in the extended reals).

* It's possible that you haven't heard of the formal definition of a limit. It is this:

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=L$ means: For all positive numbers $\epsilon$ there is a positive number $\delta$ such that for every $x$ in the interval $(c-\delta,c+\delta)$, $f(x)$ is in the interval $(L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon)$.

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$ means: For all positive numbers $\epsilon$, there is a number $N$ such that for every $x$ greater than $N$, $f(x)$ is in the interval $(L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon)$. (The symbol $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}$ is defined similarly.)

**Don't worry if you can't wrap your head around those on your first reading. Few people can.**

Technically, your limit doesn't exist, because there is no such number $L$. However, people write $\lim_{x\to\infty}e^x=\infty$, because informally, that's what $x$ tends to — infinity.

Comment: (And, to be formal: $\lim_{x\to\infty}e^x=\infty$ would mean: For every $M$, there is an $N$ such that for every $x$ greater than $N$, $e^x$ is greater than $M$.)

Answer (score 0):

Note that since $x\to\infty$, it is meaningless to think about the left and right limits because the neighborhood of $\infty$ cannot be approached. We can however use the definition of this limit to show that it is positive, unbounded and ultimately divergent. First note that
$$ \lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x) =\infty $$
Is defined by the following statement 
$$ (\forall \epsilon \gt 0)(\exists \delta \gt 0)(x \gt \delta  \Rightarrow f(x) \gt \epsilon) $$
So now let's find a value for $\delta$ that makes the statement true for $f(x)=e^x$.
$$ e^x \gt \epsilon $$
$$ \ln e^x \gt \ln \epsilon $$
$$ x \gt \ln \epsilon $$
So now choose $\delta:= \ln \epsilon$, which implies that
$$ (\forall \epsilon \gt 0)(\exists \delta \gt 0)(x \gt \ln\epsilon \Rightarrow e^x \gt \epsilon) $$
Therefore, by definition 
$$ \lim\limits_{x\to\infty} e^x=\infty $$

Comment: What's the difference between $x\to\infty^+$ and $x\to\infty^-$? $x$ can only approach $\infty$ from the left, no?

Comment: What does $\lim_{x\to\infty^+}e^x$ actually mean?

Comment: I would say it's meaningless to even write a left or right sided limit of the argument increasing (or decreasing) without bound. I think your answer is actually related to the original question in the sense that the core of the problem is confusion over the use of "$\infty$" as both something that can be "approached" and "equal to". We can only rigorously approach or equate actual numbers. In this case, the textbook author probably intends to "overload" both concepts to mean "increases without bound". That's the kind of information that would be in a helpful answer.

Comment: @ToddWilcox, thank you for your comment. Please see my edit.