# Does $[a,\infty]$ have a meaning?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We know that $[a,b]$ denotes a closed interval. And $(a,b)$ the open one. And we often denote the positive real numbers by, $\{x:x\in(0,\infty)\}$. But I remember I somewhere saw this: $$[0,\infty]$$
But what I cannot understand is, that how can infinity be ***included*** in an interval. Because infinity is not a number, not defined. So how can it be included in an interval? If it **is** included, then what is the difference between $\infty]$ and $\infty)?$

Comment: There is a notion of "extended real numbers" : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line

Comment: We take some entity that is not a real number. We call that thing $\infty$. Then we look at the set $A = \mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\}$, and declare that $x < \infty$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ (and we use the standard ordering on $\mathbb{R}\subset A$). Then we have an ordered set, and $[a,\infty]$ is an interval in $A$. (Often, one wants to add an element to "both ends", then one usually calls these $+\infty$ and $-\infty$.)

Comment: @DanielFischer. Didn't get it fully. Then what is the difference between the two: $(a,\infty) \text{ and } (a,\infty]$?

Comment: One of the two is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, the other also contains the thing we called $\infty$.

Comment: So if infinity a defined number? @DanielFischer.?

Comment: It's not a number. It's a free man. Err, forget the last sentence. But it's not a number. It's just a thing we glue to the end of $\mathbb{R}$ since it's (often, not always) useful and convenient to have such a thing.

Comment: Ohh, I got it. @DanielFischer. thank you so much !

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1226698/is-it-correct-to-say-that-lim-x-to-inftyex-infty/1226714#1226714 Stumbled upon it and it proved great!

Comment: @Gudson: I suspect that you were being downvoted because you hadn't answered the question, not because you'd made any kind of false or confusing claim.

Comment: See the edit to my question; I gave an example of when $[-\infty,+\infty]$ is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two elements $-\infty, +\infty$ are called *extended reals*.  It would be better, in your examples, to write the symbol with a sign:  $+\infty$. These are just elements that are adjoined to the reals to provide an endpoints before and after all the finite reals. They're a matter of convenience only.

The interval $[-\infty, +\infty]$ is homeomorphic to any other compact interval $[a,b]$ (for $a < b$). The difference between $[0,+\infty)$ and $[0,+\infty]$ is just like the difference between $[0,1)$ and $[0,1]$.

$±\infty$ is/are not to be confused with "NaN", alias "not a number".

Sometimes a single element called by convention $\infty$ (no sign) is adjoined a topological space such as $\mathbb{R}$ in order to form the *one-point compactification*, but that's a different notion and is not generally what is meant in discussions of calculus and analysis.

Comment: Can you give an example where $(a,\infty]$ can be used but not the open interval?

Comment: How about the function $x \mapsto \frac 1 {1-x} \colon (0, 1] \to (1, +\infty]$j. Yes that function can be extended so that $0$ is in its domain. But I mean, consider the function restricted to interval $(0, 1]$. If we're in the extended reals then it makes sense to define its value at $1$ to be $+\infty$. If not, then the domain can't include $1$ because there's no such *real* as $+\infty$.

Comment: I dont really understand $\mapsto$. Can you write the function if $f(x)$ form?

Comment: (Sorry, bear with me)

Comment: $f(x) =  \frac 1 {1-x}$

Comment: It's value can also be $-\infty$ at $x=1$, so isn't it undefined? $$\lim\limits_{x\to1}\frac1{1-x}=\text{undefined?? :)}$$

Comment: The expression $\frac 1 {1-x}$ is defined on a larger interval than $(0, 1)$ but let's say we're only interested functions on the unit interval. I'm excluding $0$ because of the example you asked for. As $x \to 1$, $lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = +\infty$ , so sometimes it's convenient to make this more than just a figure of speech and actually adjoint some new thing which will equal that limit. Then we can extend the domain to include $1$.

Comment: If 1 is approached *from the right* (via $x > 1$ then yes the limit is $-\infty$. BUT on the domain $(0,1)$ it has to approach from the left. If you extend $f$ to $(0,1]$ *and* you want it to be continuous then we have to have $f(1) = +\infty$. You *can* extend $f$ the domain of $f$ to include $x>1$ but the resulting function can't be continuous at $1$, no matter which of ±$\infty$ you designate as the value of $f(1)$.

Comment: @Aditya: Let me suggest some different functions for consideration. Let $\Bbb R^\times$ indicate the set of non-zero real numbers and $\bar{\Bbb R}$ denote the set of extended real numbers. Define the function $f:\Bbb R^\times\to\bar{\Bbb R}$ by $f(x)=\frac1{x^2}.$ The range of $f$ is $(0,+\infty).$ One notes that $f(x)\to+\infty$ as $x\to 0,$ so we can continuously extend $f$ to be defined at $0.$ We define $g:\Bbb R\to\bar{\Bbb R}$ by $g(0)=+\infty,$ and $g(x)=f(x)$ for $x\ne0.$ The range of $g$ is $(0,+\infty].$

Comment: Finally, we note that $g(x)\to0$ as $x\to+\infty$ or $x\to-\infty,$ so we can continuously extend $g$ to be defined on the extended reals. We define $h:\bar{\Bbb R}\to\bar{\Bbb R}$ by $h(+\infty)=h(-\infty)=0$ and $h(x)=g(x)$ for $x\in\Bbb R.$ The range of $h$ is $[0,+\infty].$

Answer (score 0):

The extended real line, often written as $\overline{\Bbb R}$, is defined to be $\Bbb R\cup\{-\infty,+\infty\}$.

Here, $-\infty$ and $+\infty$ can be thought of as meaningless symbols. The extended real line is just the regular real line, plus these two symbols.

Now, usually, the relation $\le$ is extended a bit when dealing with $\overline{\Bbb R}$. We define $a\le+\infty$ to be true for all $a\in\overline{\Bbb R}$, and we define $-\infty\le a$ to be true for all $a\in\overline{\Bbb R}$. These are just new definitions we made for convenience. Similarly, the operators $+$, $-$, $\times$, and $\div$ are usually extended when dealing with this set.

The set $[a,+\infty]$ is just the subset of $\overline{\Bbb R}$ consisting of everything bigger than or equal to $a$, including $+\infty$. (Note that we have $\overline{\Bbb R}=[-\infty,+\infty]$.)

---

Here's an example of when such a set could be useful. There's a theorem (called the Extreme Value Theorem, or EVT) that says that, if $f$ is a continuous function with domain $[a,b]$, then $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$.

Now, let's say we have a continuous function $f$ with domain and codomain $\Bbb R$. In addition, let's say:
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=0$$
Can we show that $f$ is bounded?

Sure! Let's extend the domain of $f$ to $\overline{\Bbb R}$, by defining $f(-\infty)=f(+\infty)=0$. This new, extended version of $f$ is still continuous, because of the limits given above. So now we have a continuous function $f$ with domain $\overline{\Bbb R}=[-\infty,+\infty]$. By the EVT, $f$ is bounded. QED.

Comment: (Note that the codomain of the extended version of $f$ is still $\Bbb R$.)